# Both local network and enterprise wifi connection on pi 3 running stretch

Tags: wifi, ethernet, raspbian-stretch, pi-3b+, mqtt

I am currently trying to build a monitor system with rpi, running stretch image, and a esp8266 nodemcu 1.0. I want to connect them using MQTT via a local network on a router. The Rpi is also connected to eduroam network with wifi and I want it to be wired with ethernet cable to the router. The connection to eduroam works fine and I can access the terminal with SSH. The problem is that when I wire it to the router it goes offline and its not accessible anymore i.e its not connected to eduroam anymore. I have been trying to understand how to modify this in stretch with no luck. So far the only thing I can think of is that its trying to use the easiest mask, which would be the ethernet when connected, instead of the wifi because when I unplug the ethernet cable it goes online again. Is there anybody here that know how to configure this in stretch so I can have both a local network connecting my devices together and also a connection to eduroam (internet). (I have to use eduroam enterprise network, no other available). All help would be much appreciated :)

Regards
Kolibri

Comment: i mean easiest metric not mask

Comment: solved. it was the metric priority..

Comment: You can post an answer below if you want to share the solution for future readers, Kolibri; then you can later accept that answer and mark this as resolved.